# Is it viable to use a SQLite database in Android with 5Mill entries taking 0.5GB?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've checked many questions here and do some deep researches about it but none of them matches my doubt.

I'm trying to develop my first app in Android, for which I'm using an external database but I'm quite stuck and probably I will leave this project.

I've done a huge database:

- 4 Tables
- 1.3M raws each table
- 18 columns each raw

I don't need to write anything on this db, just read.

The first problem is going to be the Size: ~ 450mb.

The second problem is: I'm not sure if Android is going to be able to manage a large database since this is my first app, or it's just going to crash.

Previously, I have run some test with a smaller database (100K entries) and it worked, a bit slow in Android Kitkat though.

My question is: Is there any other ways to read from an external Database ?

I was thinking about an online database, so my size problem is solved but I truly have no idea about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work just fine.  Obviously you need the proper indexes on it or searches will take a while.  Its probably easiest to download the db from the net, putting it into the apk will give Play store size problems.  Your users may not be happy with it though-  that's a lot of data for a single app.

As for an online db-  yes, you put a webservice between them with a REST API.  But going into doing that is too wide a scope for here

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I really appreciate it. I'll try to learn about online databases :)
I think is the best way to do it. 
You're right, having the db locally it's gonna make me lose users due to that big size.